# How do I build a post_thumbnail based archive?

Tags: theme-development, post-thumbnails, archives

Visually, what I'm looking for is this:
[image: grid layout]

So somehow I need to pull the date and each featured image from the years they were posted. I am in the wordpress loop.

I've looked around but couldn't find anything that I could get to work. I'm basically a php noob so be gentle!

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <p style="background-image: url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo the_title(); ?>">&nbsp;</a></p>
                <?php endwhile; else : ?>
```

Obviously this isn't working. I'm not even interacting with the database here. At first I wanted to put up all post thumbs in one grid without the year. But that might become too overwhelming.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer in a Q&A-model. What have you done so far to achieve this? Where are you stuck?

Comment: cjbj, I edited the post to reflect my feeble attempt. I know I need to grab the posts by year, then extract post thumbs but I have no idea how to query the database in such a way that would work.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to list all images that are being used as post thumbnails, or do you want to list all posts and their post thumbnails?

Comment: It was just featured images from all posts. I'm a photographer, so the emphasis on my archive were the photos. People may identify the photograph before the text content. It was important to make that happen. Did you see the working example?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to build what I did was to use different WP_Queries. I ran in to a few issues because I wanted to use the same layout for viewing categories. I know this isn't much of an answer so I did sign up on the github network and post a gist of it: [full code](https://gist.github.com/harshclimate/bcf99d6098e17028851e9f994d41bb67)

And here's what I wanted to end up with at [my website](http://www.harshclimate.com/archives)